# Different triggers for different executable tasks in the same project

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol

Is it possible in any way to have different triggers for different executable tasks within the same project?

For example: I've got several .bat-scripts that  shall be run in different intervals. 
Some once every 2 hours, some once a day and some only weekly. 
I haven't figured out yet if it's possible to have this in only one project since i want to avoid splitting them all up into their own projects in order to keep the CCTray clearly arranged.

Does anyone have an idea how i can achieve the described result within one project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it now, here is what i did:

I created several parameter triggers which all pass a different parameter and added conditions to all my tasks. Due to that i achieved what i wanted because each task only runs if the specific parameter trigger was activated and the corresponding value is set. I chose named values as parameters and compare values as condition.

Answer (score 0):

No this isn't possible. The smallest triggerable component is a project.
For this you would need to break your project into smaller ones.

Comment: You are right about the smallest triggerable component but it was still possible for me to achieve what i wanted, i've got a lot of triggers and conditional tasks now but it seems to be working. Thanks for the advice though!